# mpi4py: dynammic data processing

Tags: python, dynamic, mpi, mpi4py

I have a vector that contain stock tickers like `tickers = ['AAPL','XOM','GOOG']` and in my "traditional" python program I would loop over this `tickers` vector, select one ticker string like `AAPL`, import a csv file that contains `AAPL` stock returns, use the returns as an input to a common function, and finally generate a csv file as an output. I have over 4000 tickers and the function to apply to each ticker takes time to process. I have access to a computer cluster with the `mpi4py` package with access to about 100 processors per job. I understand well (and was able to implement) this `mpi` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812422/how-can-i-send-part-of-an-array-with-scatter/12815841#12815841) in python:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()
if rank == 0:
    data = [i for i in range(8)]
# dividing data into chunks
    chunks = [[] for _ in range(size)]
    for i, chunk in enumerate(data):
        chunks[i % size].append(chunk)
else:
    data = None
    chunks = None
data = comm.scatter(chunks, root=0)
print str(rank) + ': ' + str(data)

[cha@cluster] ~/utils> mpirun -np 3 ./mpi.py 
2: [2, 5]
0: [0, 3, 6]
1: [1, 4, 7]
```

So in this example, we have a data vector of size 8 and assign to each processor (3 in total) an equal number of elements of the data. How can I use the similar above example and assign to each processor one stock ticker and apply the function that needs to be run for each ticker? How can I tell python that once a processor get free, to go back in the `tickers` vector and process a `ticker` that has not yet been processed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another way to think of this. You have 100 processors processing 4000 chunks of data. One way you can look at this is that each processor gets a block of data on which to operate. Evenly split, each processor will get 40 tickers to process. Processor 1 will get 0-39, processor 2 will get 40-79, etc.

Thinking this way, you don't need to worry about what happens when a processor finishes its tasks. Just have a loop:

```
block_size = len(tickers) / size # this will be 40 in your example
for i in range(block_size):
    ticker = tickers[rank * block_size + i]
    process(ticker)

def process(ticker):
    # load data
    # process data
    # output data
```

Does this make sense?

[edit]
If you're wanting to read more, this is really just a variation on [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) indexing, a common method for accessing multidimensional data that's stored in a single dimension of memory.

Comment: thanks for your insights. I will try your suggestion later today! Thank you

Comment: So you replace all this:
`data = [i for i in range(8)]
# dividing data into chunks
    chunks = [[] for _ in range(size)]
    for i, chunk in enumerate(data):
        chunks[i % size].append(chunk)
else:
    data = None
    chunks = None`
by what you have suggested correct? And the process(.) is my function that process the tickers return right?

Comment: Yeah, I'm suggesting you get rid of the entire `if...else` block and replace it with what I have above. Then, just implement the `process` function that actually does this work.

Comment: If you want to actually see this in action, just replace the `process` call to `print('%d - %s' % (rank, my_ticker_string))`, and I think that'll clear up any confusion you might have.

Comment: Ok I see ... but the function that I apply to each tickers: load the .txt files, process the data, and output everything back in CSV for each tickers ... where in the code can I apply this data processing? Imagine I create another file with the function `def process_job(ticker)` and I import this function ... where in the code you have suggested I have to write the `process_job` function so that I get the desired output? thanks Geoff for the help

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I included `process`. What I called `process` in my code is what you're calling `process_job`. Just define that function in that same script, and you can call it as I showed in the for loop. I'll edit my example above to demonstrate this.

Comment: Ok Great Geoff! Sorry I wanted to implement your suggestion tonight but I will have to wait until tomorrow. Thanks a lot for your suggestions and I will get back to you shortly.

Comment: I am giving a try now Geoff - thanks for your patience

Comment: I should have thought about this before but what if the `len(tickers)/size` is not a round number? I could simply round up but that would be problematic. Also `data = comm.scatter(chunks, root=0)` this will need to become `data = comm.scatter(ticker, root=0)` correct? Is it the `comm.scatter` that assign each chunk of data and its process (my function) to each processors?

Comment: it should `ticker = comm.scatter(ticker, root=0)` ... but will my function be applied to each `ticker` before the actual "separation" of my data to each processors? The tickers must be assign to each procs before the function kicks in.

Comment: no wait.... maybe I don't need the comm.scatter since I don't care about aggregating all the jobs when they are done

Comment: The easiest way to handle the edge case is to not deal with it. Just reserve a job size that makes sense. You're got the right idea - you don't need `comm.scatter` here. Each processor needs access to the entire array for this to work; they access only the data they're allotted.

Comment: I have to wait before my job can be run on the cluster and see if it works out. I will approve your answer but if I have more questions I will ask you if you don't mind. Thanks Geoff

Comment: everything is running great!!

Comment: I'm still curious how to do what the OP originally asked. This answer is good if all tasks take roughly the same time to complete, but if there is larger variation in task times then a lot of tasks will simply sit idle waiting for the slowest ones to finish. In such cases it would be good if tasks instead request and fetch tasks dynamically as soon as they are available. If anyone has an answer for that using mpi4py I would be very curious to see it.